How to search mutliple columns in mysql with partial matching (?) similar to a search bar?
I am writing a Java command line app for searching through books in a library and outputing the location of the book to the user. The books are stored in a mysql database and all access is done through the java app. I want users to be able to search the inventory with partial titles/isbn's, similar to how the search bar is in this website. If its possible in java/mysql i also want to add a autocorrect/complete feature similar to how google corrects a typo in a search. I tried searching for solutions online but haven't been able to find anything similar, possibly due to not knowing the correct terms.
I considered using the Java app to do the searching instead of mysql but thought it would be too resource intensive considering the server only has 8gb of ram with a 4th gen i5. The search functions are going to be limited to registered users but that is something I will add later. The code for the java app and mysql database is below. Thanks in advance for your answers!
App.java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Scanner;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://172.26.114.217:3306/mydb", "root", "1234");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Database connection failed: " + e);
            return;
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isRunning = true;
        boolean isAuthenticated = false;
        String username = null;

        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                if (!isAuthenticated) {
                    System.out.println("Select an option: 1. Signup 2. Login 3. Exit");
                    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline

                    switch (choice) {
                        case 1:
                            Helper.signup(con);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            isAuthenticated = Helper.login(con);
                            if (isAuthenticated) {
                                System.out.println("Login successful.");
                                username = Helper.getUsername();
                                System.out.println("Welcome " + username);
                                Helper.readLastLogin(con, username);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            isRunning = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Select an option: 1. Logout 2. Exit");
                    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline

                    switch (choice) {
                        case 1:
                            isAuthenticated = false;
                            System.out.println("Logged out successfully.");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            isRunning = false;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                scanner.nextLine(); // Consume newline if invalid input
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
        try {
            if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to close the database connection: " + e);
        }
    }
}

Helper.java (contains all login and signup functions, library functionality will be in another class)
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Console;

public class Helper {

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Console cons = System.console();
    private static String currentUsername;

    public static boolean login(Connection con) {
        System.out.println("Enter Username:");
        String uname = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Password:");
        String plainpass = readPasswordtoString();
        String passhash = Password.makePass(plainpass);
        try {
            PreparedStatement loginstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT passhash FROM member WHERE uname = ?;");
            loginstmt.setString(1, uname);
            ResultSet loginrs = loginstmt.executeQuery();
            if (loginrs.next()) {
                if (loginrs.getString("passhash").equals(passhash)) {
                    currentUsername = uname;
                    writeLoginTime(con);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid username or password.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("User not found.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void writeLoginTime(Connection con) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement loginstampstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE member SET lastlogin = ? WHERE uname = ?");
            loginstampstmt.setString(1, timeStamp());
            loginstampstmt.setString(2, currentUsername);
            loginstampstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void readLastLogin(Connection con, String uname) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement loginreadstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT lastlogin FROM member WHERE uname = ?;");
            loginreadstmt.setString(1, uname);
            ResultSet loginreadrs = loginreadstmt.executeQuery();
            if (loginreadrs.next()){
                System.out.println("Last seen: " + (loginreadrs.getString("lastlogin")));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("First login, welcome!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void signup(Connection con) {
        System.out.println("Enter Username:"); // same as login
        String uname = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
        String fName = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Last Name:");
        String sName = s.nextLine();
        boolean passMatch = false;
        String plainpass;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Password:");
            plainpass = readPasswordtoString();
            System.out.println("Reenter Password:");
            if (readPasswordtoString().equals(plainpass)) {
                passMatch = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Passwords do not match!");
            }
        } while (!passMatch);
        String passHash = Password.makePass(plainpass);
        try {
            PreparedStatement signupstmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO member (uname, fname, sname, passhash) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");
            signupstmt.setString(1, uname);
            signupstmt.setString(2, fName);
            signupstmt.setString(3, sName);
            signupstmt.setString(4, passHash);
            signupstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Signup complete, proceed to login.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        return currentUsername;
    }

    public static String timeStamp() {
        return ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss"));
    }

    private static String readPasswordtoString(){
        char[] passchars = cons.readPassword();
        return new String(passchars);
    }
}

Password.java (exclusively for hashing passwords)
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class Password {
    private static String password = null;
    private static String encryptedpassword = null;

    public static String makePass(String plainpass) {
        try {
            /* MessageDigest instance for MD5. */
            MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            password = plainpass;

            /* Add plain-text password bytes to digest using MD5 update() method. */
            m.update(password.getBytes());

            /* Convert the hash value into bytes */
            byte[] bytes = m.digest();

            /*
             * The bytes array has bytes in decimal form. Converting it into hexadecimal
             * format.
             */
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                s.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }

            /* Complete hashed password in hexadecimal format */
            encryptedpassword = s.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedpassword;
    }
}

mysql database create script: (can upload model if needed):
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Tue Jul 16 18:18:44 2024
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`author`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`author` (
  `idauthor` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `authorfname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `authorsname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idauthor`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idauthor_UNIQUE` (`idauthor` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`language`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`language` (
  `idlang` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `languagename` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlang`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `languagename_UNIQUE` (`languagename` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idlang_UNIQUE` (`idlang` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`publisher`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`publisher` (
  `idpublisher` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `publishername` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpublisher`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `publishername_UNIQUE` (`publishername` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idpublisher_UNIQUE` (`idpublisher` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`book`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`book` (
  `idbook` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookname` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
  `idauthor` INT NOT NULL,
  `idtype` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `idlang` INT NOT NULL,
  `pubyear` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `idpublisher` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idbook`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idbook_UNIQUE` (`idbook` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `idauthor_idx` (`idauthor` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `idlang_idx` (`idlang` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `idpublisher_idx` (`idpublisher` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idauthor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idauthor`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`author` (`idauthor`),
  CONSTRAINT `idlang`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idlang`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`language` (`idlang`),
  CONSTRAINT `idpublisher`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idpublisher`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`publisher` (`idpublisher`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`member`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`member` (
  `idmember` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `fname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `sname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `passhash` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmember`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idmember_UNIQUE` (`idmember` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `uname_UNIQUE` (`uname` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `phone_UNIQUE` (`phone` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`loan`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`loan` (
  `idmember` INT NOT NULL,
  `takedate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `idbook` INT NOT NULL,
  `returndate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmember`, `takedate`, `idbook`),
  INDEX `idbook_idx` (`idbook` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `idbook`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idbook`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`book` (`idbook`),
  CONSTRAINT `idmember`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idmember`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`member` (`idmember`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb3;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;


Radix trie.
